# RHEL patch => phpMyadmin errors 5.5+ required

Tags: mysql, redhat, rhel6, phpmyadmin

A recent RHEL patch has broken our server's config and various other issues.
One specifically is phpMyAdmin throws the following error:
                 `PHP 5.5+ is required`

How would an upgrade of RHEL downgrade PHP or would it alter PHP at all? I'm not the server admin just a developer trying to resolve a number of issues after the patch.

The app having the issues is run using Apache, php, MySQL more or less a LAMPP stack. The current version of PHP that is present is 5.3.3. Just trying to understand what the patch would have changed and how to get around the phpmyadmin error requiring a higher version.

Assuming my only option is to upgrade as the error suggests, what is the best course of action? I don't want to lose the DB or configure any of the applications files.

Comment: best course of action would be to restore a working backup)

Comment: You may also want to take this opportunity to evaluation why exactly you need phpMyAdmin, and whether or not you could just use one of the myriad workstation tools to perform the same tasks (via an SSH tunnel) in a much more reliable, secure manner.

Comment: @alexus I've been told there hasn't been a backup for sometime of all the necessary files for sometime. We've restored some of the config file prior to the server patch but no luck.

Comment: Are you using the packaged version of phpMyAdmin or did you install it yourself from the source?

Comment: @ibennetch The version that came with the LAMPP stack is what is currently there. Here are the version number:php Version: 5.3.3.48
MySQL Version:5.1.73-5. I'll have to find the version of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your PHP, as it's starting to get old. It's a security risk. I more think the update did updated phpmyadmin, that now in turn want PHP 5.5+.

For PHP,
End of Life: 5.3 -  **14 Aug 2014** - 2 years, 5 months ago.

There is a migration guide there: https://secure.php.net/migration54